# Stacking typing effect with fadeIn effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, let's see if this makes sense. I'm still very much a novice, and I'm trying to keep this simple so I understand every step of the process.

**What I would like to do:** Currently I have a typewriter effect on a block of text. Once it is done 'typing', I would like to be able to have the current text fade out and the next block of text start in with the same typing effect. I've successfully written this sequential fadein effect for other pages, but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

**JQuery script:**
The sequential fadeIn script I'm using on other pages looks like this:

```
    $('.wrapper').on('click', function () {
        var currentText = $('.active');
        var next = currentText.next('p');

        if (next.length > 0) {
            currentText.fadeOut(400).removeClass('active');
            next.delay(200).fadeIn(1100).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

This is what I'm using for my typewriter function too:

```
    var text = $(".typeText").text();

    $.each(text.split(''), function (i, letter) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.typewriter').html($('.typewriter').html() + letter);
        }, 50 * i);
    });
```

However, when I try to combine the two (doing `var text=$('.typeText .active'` for instance), it doesn't work at all. What's the best way to 'clear' the .typewriter div and re-get the text content from the 'typeText' class on each click?

Here's the JSFiddle I've set up with my (nonworking) code in it if that helps. http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/tp42qqp9/7/

Thank you!!!

Comment: To reduce the complexity of the code you may use some typing library like [shabdawali](https://github.com/amitguptagwl/shabdawali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/jd1Lwjyo/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var typing = false;

    $('.wrapper').on('click', function () {
        typeIn();
    });

    function typeIn(){
        if(typing) return;
        var currentText = $('.typeText.active');
        var text = currentText.text();
        var next = currentText.next('.typeText');
        var typeWriter = $('.typewriter');

        typing = true;

        if (currentText.length > 0) {
            typeWriter.fadeOut(400,function(){
                var textSplit = text.split(''),
                    textLgth = textSplit.length;
                typeWriter.html('').show();
                $.each(textSplit, function (i, letter) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        typeWriter.html(typeWriter.html() + letter);
                        if(textLgth-1 === i) typing = false;
                    }, 500 * i);
                });

            });
            if(next.length) next.addClass('active');
            currentText.removeClass('active');
        }
    }

    typeIn();
});
```

Comment: YES that's perfect!! Thank you!!! One other thing -- how much more complicated is it to make sure that the current text fades out ONLY if it's done 'typing'?

Comment: I updated my code to add it. And I increased the time, to let you try to click when it's typing. Is it what you expected ?